# Merge multiple .txt/csv files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple `.txt` files in a directory and I want to merge them into one by importing in python. The catch here is that after the merge I want to convert it into one `csv` file on which the whole program is based.

So far I only had to input one `.txt` file and converted it into `csv` file by this code:

```
import io
bytes = open('XYZ.txt', 'rb').read()
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(bytes.decode('utf-8')), sep='\t', parse_dates=['Time'] )
df.head()
```

Now I need to input multiple `.txt` files, merge them and then convert them into csv files. Any workaround?

Comment: Are the headers of your files the same?

Comment: Yes. Just need to merge the data in the columns

Comment: you don't need pandas to do this if thats all its doing, csv module in the standard library would do fine

Comment: also those are commonly referred to as [tsv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) files, so really your question is about converting tsv to csv?

Answer (score 3):

If the headers are same then it should be as easy as this

```
import os
import io

merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir("PATH_OF_DIRECTORY"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        bytes = open(file, 'rb').read()
        merged_df = merged_df.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
            bytes.decode('utf-8')), sep='\t', parse_dates=['Time']))

print(len(merged_df))
```

Comment: You can manipulate list of files by doing some string filter or regex operations.

Comment: Can you please tell how I can edit it so that it only takes .txt files?

Comment: There are 4 .txt files in the directory and it is only taking in one. Working same like the code which I wrote for reading 1 file

Comment: Then make sure path is right and all the extensions are exactly ".txt" (matching the case)as this is very straightforward code.

Comment: Path is alright as it is reading one file. And the other files are also .txt. Not working. Weird. Thanks anyway man!

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
path="location/of/folder"
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "\\*.txt")

list_ = []
for file in allFiles:
    print(file)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file.decode('utf-8')), sep='\t', parse_dates=['Time'])
    list_.append(df)
combined_files = pd.concat(list_)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you thing this is a solution? How is your code different from the one in the question?